# Using FontAwesome icons as HighChart markers

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I found this useful [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ecx81d5/5/) about how to use FontAwesome as markers in HighChart. The idea is to use the icons' unicode to plug in HighChart.

```
marker: {
            symbol: 'text:\uf0c8',
            
        },
```

However in FontAwesome, both solid and regular versions of the same shape share the same unicode. For example, [solid square](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/square?style=solid) and [regular square](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/square?style=regular). If I use their unicode, the HighChart marker is always the solid version. How do I change the marker to the regular version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that fiddle, it is using font-awesome 4.1.0, so if you want to use the regular square it should be:

```
marker: {
   symbol: 'text:\uf096',            
},
```

Comment: it works, thanks. Just curious where did you find that unicode for the regular square?

Comment: @TDo just find it on [the icon list](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/icon/square-o) and inspect html

Comment: sorry for a follow up question. I just checked and turns out my website needs font-awesome version 5 so I try changing the version of font-awesome in the fiddle to 5 but then the unicode `f096` does not show anything anymore. Do you know how to make this work with font-awesome 5? Thanks a lot. This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/psg1jn93/14/

Comment: @TDo try this [http://jsfiddle.net/4xrqhs6p/](http://jsfiddle.net/4xrqhs6p/). Then can mark my answer marked?. Thanks :D

Comment: If you don't mind, I swear this will be the last follow up question :D. I am trying to add the fontAwesome icons inside the tooltip but it seems like the icons are not rendered correctly. Do you happen to know the reason? Thanks a lot in advance. http://jsfiddle.net/acmrefgu/20/

Comment: I copied the Unicode character and paste it to the formatter icon function : [http://jsfiddle.net/wz3o4f9u/](http://jsfiddle.net/wz3o4f9u/)

Comment: sorry for a stupid question, how do I copy the Unicode character of a font awesome icon?

Comment: You can see that icons is on the left near the Unicode character, then click into it.

Comment: just in case you know the answer, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69774814/highcharts-markers-in-line-charts-move-up-when-leaving-hovering

Comment: @lamtacvu Thanks for this, it worked for me after I upgraded from FA4 to FA5. The important but was textn for symbol. I made all of the other changes and nothing worked, until I noticed that it was "textn" now and not "text". I spun my wheels for several hours.