# Highcharts - Markers in line charts move up when leaving hovering

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use Font Awesome icons as markers in HighCharts line chart. With help from fellow developers on Stack Overflow, I have managed to do that. One problem left is that now, whenever I hover over the markers and then leave hovering, they just move up a bit from the line and stay there forever. I really have no idea why.

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vf0g4u5k/12/. Appreciate any help.

The plug-in to use Font Awesome with HighCharts

```
(function (H) {
    function symbolWrap(proceed, symbol, x, y, w, h, options) {
        if (symbol.indexOf('text:') === 0) {
            var text = symbol.split(':')[1],
                svgElem = this.text(text, x, y + h)
                .css({
                    fontFamily: '"Font Awesome 5 Free"',
                    fontSize: (h * 2 ) + "px"
                });
            
            if (svgElem.renderer.isVML) {
                svgElem.fillSetter = function (value, key, element) {
                    element.style.color = H.Color(value).get('rgb');
                };
            }
            return svgElem;
        }
        if (symbol.indexOf('textn:') === 0) {
            var text = symbol.split(':')[1],
                svgElem = this.text(text, x, y + h)
                .css({
                    fontFamily: '"Font Awesome 5 Free"',
                    fontSize: (h * 2 ) + "px",
                    fontWeight: 900
                });
            
            if (svgElem.renderer.isVML) {
                svgElem.fillSetter = function (value, key, element) {
                    element.style.color = H.Color(value).get('rgb');
                };
            }
            return svgElem;
        }
        
        
        return proceed.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
    H.wrap(H.SVGRenderer.prototype, 'symbol', symbolWrap);
    if (H.VMLRenderer) {
        H.wrap(H.VMLRenderer.prototype, 'symbol', symbolWrap);
    }
    
    // Load the font for SVG files also
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'getSVG', function (proceed) {
        var svg = proceed.call(this);
        svg = '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" ' +
            'href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" ?>' + 
            svg;
        return svg;
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

Comment: I think it is actually from core code of Highcharts in the section of animating marker (handle the custom character in marker converting into svg path), which we cant changes. Reloading series after load does the trick but I think if you can you custom marker image rather font-awesome, it will not have any issue like this.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing like this. Posting in case it may help someone else.

```
point: {
                        events: {
                            mouseOut: function() {
                                var index = this.index
                                for( var series of this.series.chart.series){
                                    for(var j=0;j<series.points.length;j++){
                                        if(j === index && series.points[j].graphic){series.points[j].graphic.attr({'translateY': 8})}
                                    }
                                };
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your custom marker settings by setting translateX and translateY like this

```
            var text = symbol.split(':')[1],
                svgElem = this.text(text, x, y)
                .attr({
                  translateY: h,
                  translateX: -1
                })
                .css({
                    fontFamily: '"Font Awesome 5 Free"',
                    fontSize: (h * 2 ) + "px"
                });
```