# Customization options using network chart?

Tags: highcharts

I'm a former user of some network graph libs (dataviz, v-network-graph)...

If I leave the first one if favor of the latest one, I'm still facing some issues I'm looking to solve.

I'm having a look on highchartJs, which, even not being free, looks promising and seems way much easier to use.

My needs are quiet simple:

- I need a complete interaction support (selection, drag&drop...)
- I need to be able to change the map dynamically (Cannot presume which nodes will be here)
- I need to be able to customize nodes. Not I dislike bubbles, but I want to use custom icons instead of default plots.

From the documentation, I think that HighchartJS is absolutely capable, but there still is one point I cannot reply...

Is it possible to use custom svg icons instead of colored plots? If so, where should I find documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, you can achieve all of your requirements by using Highcharts.

It's also possible to use custom SVG icons instead of colored plots, just use the `series.marker.symbol` option to define a common symbol for all series nodes or `series.nodes.marker.symbol` for a specific one.

```
  series: [{
    marker: {
        symbol: 'url(...)'
    },
    data: [
      ...
    ]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7m5p3j2x/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.marker.symbol

**Useful threads:**

https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=45874

[Using FontAwesome icons as HighChart markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69731208/using-fontawesome-icons-as-highchart-markers)

Comment: I finally did it before I saw your answer, but this one is absolutely correct and match 100% the way I did it. Useful for future users.